# REST opaque links and frontend of app

Tags: web-services, rest

In REST URIs should be opaque to the client.
But when you build interactive javascript-based web-client for your application you actually have two clients! One for interaction with server and other one for users (actual GUI). Of course you will want to have friendly URIs, good enough to answer the question "where am I now?".

It's easier when a server just respond with HTML so people can just click on links and don't care about structure. Server provides URIs, server receives URIs.

It's easier with desktop client. The same staff. Just a button "show the resource" and user doesn't care what the URI is.

It's complicated with browser clients. There is the address bar. This leads to the fact that low-level part of web-client relies on the URIs structure of a server. Which is not RESTful.

It seems like the space between frontend and backend of the application is too tight for REST.

Does it mean that REST is not a good choice for reactive interactive js-based browser clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're a little confused...

First of all, your initial assumption is flawed. URI opacity doesn't mean URIs have to be cryptic. It only means that clients should not rely on URI semantics for interaction. Friendly URIs are not only allowed, they are encouraged for the exact same reason you talk about: it's easier for developers to know what's going on.

Roy Fielding [made that clear](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/topics/3232) in the REST mailing list years ago, but it seems like that's a myth that won't go away easily:

> REST does not require that a URI be opaque. The only place where the
>   word opaque occurs in my dissertation is where I complain about the
>   opaqueness of cookies. In fact, RESTful applications are, at all
>   times, encouraged to use human-meaningful, hierarchical identifiers in
>   order to maximize the serendipitous use of the information beyond what
>   is anticipated by the original application.

Second, you say it's easier when a server just respond with HTML so people can just follow links and don't care about structure. Well, that's exactly what REST is supposed to do. REST is merely a more formal and abstract definition of the architecture style of the web itself. Do some research on REST and HATEOAS.

Finally, to answer your question, whether REST is a good choice for you is not determined by client implementation details like that. You can have js-based clients, no problem, but the need to do that isn't reason enough to worry too much about getting REST right. REST is a good choice if you have projects with long term integration, maintainability and evolution goals. If you need something quick, that won't change a lot, or won't be integrated with a lot of different clients and services, don't worry too much about REST.

Comment: Thanks. I choose REST exactly because the project is a SaaS app, so should be as much scalable and maintainable as possible. Some of practices and patterns helped a lot, but some are confusing when you're missing the point. There are common rules for resourceful URIs which covers almost all cases. Now I think if client and server use the same URI convention it makes interaction enough transparent and easy. Anyway I don't make a web-browser at all, I make the client for the exact application. It has a right to know the application API URIs at least a bit =)